# What is the best way to track facebook comment widget in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-analytics, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to apply event tracking in google analytics to facebook comments made on our website via the facebook social plugin (iframe widget), but I can't seem to find a way to attach the event. I would prefer if the solution was jquery based, but honostly I'm open to most any suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Facebook JS SDK Event Subscriptions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), specifically `comment.create` event callback.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){ 
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Facebook Comment", "Posted", response.commentID]);
});
```

You can also track comment deletions with `comment.remove`

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function(response){ 
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Facebook Comment", "Deleted", response.commentID]);
});
```

I've tested this, and both appear to work reliably. If you have any troubles, try clearing your cache, and be sure to check the [Facebook SDK Status Page](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status).

If you're loading the Facebook SDK asynchronously, those calls should be placed in the asynchronous callback function. If you're loading the SDK synchronously, they just need to be placed lower on the page than the SDK.

The response object will have the `commentID`, as well as a `href` attribute, and a `parentCommentID`, if the comment is a reply to another comment (otherwise, it is set to `undefined`).

The `href` attribute's purpose is unclear, but its contents appear to be composed as follows:

> http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments_v1.php?app_id=[your-app-id]&xid=276&url=[encodeURIComponent(location.href)]

Comment: Just a quick comment for anyone else trying this out, if you're using the appid to determine admins for chat, apparently your own comments don't fire the event - but this works fine when I tested it using a "regular" user account.

Comment: @Ramiro whoa, that's weird. Thanks for sharing!