# Detect when facebook comments have loaded?

Tags: facebook

I'm using:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.WEBSITE.com" data-num-posts="5" data-width="655"></div>
```

...for Facebook comments, but obviously it takes a few seconds to load all the comments in.

Is there a way for me to detect when all the comments have loaded - perhaps somesort of callback which will fire when complete?

Thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312538/what-is-the-best-way-to-track-facebook-comment-widget-in-google-analytics

Comment: Isn't that for when a new comment is added, rather than when the page loads existing comments (which is what I want) ?

Comment: Oh right... My apologies, I misread "loaded" as "posted". Have you tried using the render event? or the status changed event? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/